# The asynctask part of my code closes/stops the app whenever I click the back/home button

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask, runnable

Can anyone help me solve the error in my asynctask? I think I know why it gives an error but I don't know what to do to solve it. Thank you very much.

here is my asynctask code (just want to use it for a joystick using surfaceview)

```
public class MySurfaceThread extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


    SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
    CustomSurfaceView cSurfaceView;


    public MySurfaceThread(SurfaceHolder sh, CustomSurfaceView csv) {
        mSurfaceHolder = sh;
        cSurfaceView = csv;
        x = y = 0;

        cSurfaceView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                x = event.getX();
                y = event.getY();

                calculateValues(x, y);

                switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        x = y = 0;
                        dx = dy = 0;
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:

                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                        break;
                }

                return true;
            }

            private void calculateValues(float xx, float yy) {
                dx = xx - zeroX;
                dy = yy - zeroY;
                angle = (float)Math.atan(Math.abs(dy/dx));
                hyp = (float)Math.sqrt((dx * dx) + (dy * dy));

                if(hyp > radius) {
                    if(dx > 0 && dy > 0){ //bottom right
                        xx = (zeroX + (radius*(float)Math.cos(angle)));
                        yy = (zeroY + (radius*(float)Math.sin(angle)));
                    }
                    else if(dx > 0 && dy < 0){ //top right
                        xx = (zeroX + (radius*(float)Math.cos(angle)));
                        yy = (zeroY - (radius*(float)Math.sin(angle)));
                    }

                    else if(dx < 0 && dy < 0){ //top left
                        xx = (zeroX - (radius*(float)Math.cos(angle)));
                        yy = (zeroY - (radius*(float)Math.sin(angle)));
                    }

                    else if(dx < 0 && dy > 0) { //bottom left
                        xx = (zeroX - (radius*(float)Math.cos(angle)));
                        yy = (zeroY + (radius*(float)Math.sin(angle)));
                    }
                }

                else {
                    xx = zeroX + dx;
                    yy = zeroY + dy;
                }

                x = xx;
                y = yy;
            }


        });
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Canvas canvas = null;

        while (running) {
            try {
                canvas = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                synchronized (mSurfaceHolder) {
                    zeroX = canvas.getWidth()/2;
                    zeroY = canvas.getHeight()/2;
                    cSurfaceView.onDraw(canvas, x, y, zeroX, zeroY);
                }
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            } finally {
                if (canvas != null) {
                    mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Can I do the same task using runnable and thread? If so, how? thank you.

**EDIT**

Here is the error message in the logcat:

```
03-09 15:23:52.394    4135-4159/com.example.r.bluetoothsample E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
Process: com.example.r.bluetoothsample, PID: 4135
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.r.bluetoothsample.CustomSurfaceView$MySurfaceThread.doInBackground(CustomSurfaceView.java:182)
        at com.example.r.bluetoothsample.CustomSurfaceView$MySurfaceThread.doInBackground(CustomSurfaceView.java:95)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: added the logcat. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`lockCanvas()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.html#lockCanvas%28%29) will return null if your surface is unavailable (which I assume it becomes when you leave your activity). That means you'll run into a `NullPointerException` at your `getWidth()` call.

On a side note, I hope you're stopping that background loop (maybe by setting `running` to `false`?) in your activity's `onPause()` method -- otherwise, it'll keep looping in the background, which is undesirable.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer. I first tried removing the null in the `lockCanvas()` but still my problem is that when I click back/home button, it says that the app unfortunately stopped. Will setting the running value to false in onPause method solve it? Actually I don't have `onPause()` method in my code. How will I implement that? I'm just new in android and just saw a tutorial on how to make a joystick. Thank you very much

Comment: By "removing the null in `lockCanvas()`", do you mean removing the `null` argument? That's not what I meant: the method can *return* null. You have to check the return value (`canvas`) before using it. No, stopping your background thread will not fix this problem (well, sometimes, if you're really lucky with the timing, but as programmers, we don't rely on luck). Regarding `onPause()`: read up on the Android Acticity lifecycle.

Comment: Oh, okay. How can I check the value? Hmm, from what I searched, they say that stopping the asynctask will prevent the error because it is still running whenever I click back/home button. I'm sorry for asking so many questions, I'm just new to android. Thank you.

Comment: `if (canvas != null)` to check the value; then do stuff only if it was OK. Regarding stopping the task: it's not a guarantee, because you can't know that the task hasn't just started a new iteration of the loop (and so will only stop after one last try... which will crash your app).

Comment: Thanks! I'm just thinking how will I set `running` to false in `onPause()` because it is in another java file.

Comment: Just did the check value thing and the app did not say 'unfortunately stopped'. Thank you again